# space-between not working on loading page

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have created a loading page with css and html. I would like to display a loading bar to display when the page is loading, between 0% to 100%.I have used justify-content:space-between to solve this but I can't seem to make this work. I have read previous posts on this in the forum but am still stuck. here is my code, both html and css

```
<body>
    <div class="loading">
        <div class="loading__box">
            <div class="loading__text">
                <div class="loading__text--border"></div>
                L
                <div class="loading__text--dot"></div>
                OADING EXPERIENCE
            </div>
            <div class="loading__bar">
                <div class="loading__bar--inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="loading__counter">
                <span>0%</span> 
                <div class="loading__counter--number">100%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

base.scss

````
body {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &::after,
    &::before {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

loader.scss

```
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #0b134f;
    place-items: center;
    display: grid;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
    &__box {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid #6cff8d;
        border-top: 3px solid #6cff8c7a;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #6cff8c7a;
    }
    &__bar {
        width: 90%;
        height: 10%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translateX(-50%);
       background: #ccc;
       border-radius: 2px;
       &--inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: #6cff8d;
       }
    }
    &__text {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 1rem;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        &--dot {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            margin: 0 3px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: pulse  1s infinite;
            background: #fff;
            @keyframes pulse {
                from {
                    opacity: 0;
                    background: #6cff8d;
                }
                to {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }

        &--border {
            width: 85%;
            height: 1px;
            background: #6cff8c7a;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
    }
    &__counter {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70%;
        left: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        width: 100px;
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit you `.loading__counter`:

```
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0 10px;
```

See the working example below:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &::after,
    &::before {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.loading {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 99;
     background: #0b134f;
     place-items: center;
     display: grid;
     font-family: &#34;
    Orbitron&#34;
    , sans-serif;
}
 .loading__box {
     position: relative;
     width: 500px;
     height: 200px;
     border: 3px solid #6cff8d;
     border-top: 3px solid #6cff8c 7a;
     border-bottom: 3px solid #6cff8c 7a;
}
 .loading__bar {
     width: 90%;
     height: 10%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     background: #ccc;
     border-radius: 2px;
}
 .loading__bar--inner {
     height: 100%;
     width: 50%;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background: #6cff8d;
}
 .loading__text {
     position: relative;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 1rem;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 700;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .loading__text--dot {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     margin: 0 3px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     animation: pulse 1s infinite;
     background: #fff;
}
 @keyframes pulse {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         background: #6cff8d;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
 .loading__text--border {
     width: 85%;
     height: 1px;
     background: #6cff8c 7a;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 50px;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}
 .loading__counter {
     position: absolute;
     top: 70%;
     left: 0;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 700;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="loading">
        <div class="loading__box">
            <div class="loading__text">
                <div class="loading__text--border"></div>
                L
                <div class="loading__text--dot"></div>
                OADING EXPERIENCE
            </div>
            <div class="loading__bar">
                <div class="loading__bar--inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="loading__counter">
                <span>0%</span> 
                <div class="loading__counter--number">100%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, adding box-sizing: border-box and padding: 0 10px, solved it. Thanks again